# The cause of "bad magic number" error when loading a workspace and how to avoid it?

Tags: r, workspace, magic-numbers

I tried to load my R workspace and received this error:

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘WORKSPACE_Wedding_Weekend_September’ has magic number '#gets'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I'm not particularly interested in the technical details, but mostly in how I caused it and how I can prevent it in the future.  Here's some notes on the situation:

1. I'm running R 2.15.1 on a MacBook Pro running Windows XP on a bootcamp partition.
2. There is something obviously wrong this workspace file, since it weighs in at only ~80kb while all my others are usually >10,000
3. Over the weekend I was running an external modeling program in R and storing its output to different objects.  I ran several iterations of the model over the course of several days, eg output_Saturday <- call_model()
4. There is nothing special to the model output, its just a list with slots for betas, VC-matrices, model specification, etc.

Comment: Guess: it's not a workspace file, it's a log of the R commands.

Comment: I suspect the same, try loading it with `source(filename)` instead of `load(filename)`.

Comment: Bummmer - Will have to check.  I wish I could claim is was a beginners mistake.

Comment: Similar to what @JoshuaUlrich said, I `load`ed something I had `write.table`ed rather than `save`ed and got this error. Oops.

Comment: Got this error when I load a database with `load`, where `loadDb` should be used.

Comment: Can you please provide info regarding the type of the file (is this .RData file)? and what exactly function did you use here (`load`?)

Answer (score 156):

I got that error when I accidentally used `load()` instead of `source()` or `readRDS()`.

Comment: So did I, when I accidentally used `load()` instead of `read.csv()`. :p

Comment: So did I, part 2, when I accidentally used `load()` instead of `readRDS()` (yes, 9 months later, I'm back here for pretty much the same mistake).

Comment: This also happened to me, but the reason was different: a teammate sent me an rds file with an incorrect .rdata extension, so I tried using load(), got the error, then tried readRDS() and it worked.

Comment: Great, I get this error when I use `load` and when I use `readRDS` I get `unknown input format`. Should I just cry?

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera Thanks, this worked! I had the same problem - someone else had saved files (from about 2 years ago), and I couldn't open them.  Simply using `readRDS()` worked - no need to change the file extension from Rdata first.

Answer (score 48):

Also worth noting the following from a document by the R Core Team summarizing changes in versions of R after v3.5.0 ([here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018-1/ch.pdf)):

*R has new serialization format (version 3) which supports custom serialization of
ALTREP framework objects... **Serialized data in format 3 cannot be read by versions of R prior to version 3.5.0.***

I encountered this issue when I saved a workspace in v3.6.0, and then shared the file with a colleague that was using v3.4.2. I was able to resolve the issue by adding "version=2" to my save function.

Comment: Thanks! This helped in my case (had just installed  R from ubuntu repository - and tried to open an RData file I had created a few weeks ago on another machine using a slightly newer version of R)

Answer (score 20):

Assuming your file is named "myfile.ext"

If the file you're trying to load is not an R-script, for which you would use

```
source("myfile.ext")
```

you might try the `readRDS`function and assign it to a variable-name:

```
my.data <- readRDS("myfile.ext")
```

Answer (score 10):

The magic number comes from UNIX-type systems where the first few bytes of a file held a marker indicating the file type.

This error indicates you are trying to load a non-valid file type into R. For some reason, R no longer recognizes this file as an R workspace file.

Answer (score 8):

It also occurs when you try to `load()` an rds object instead of using

```
object <- readRDS("object.rds")
```

Answer (score 7):

Install the `readr` package, then use `library(readr)`.

Comment: Nice trick... I had to try a couple of the packs function but with `readr::` it's easy to scan through the functions. `readr::read_rds` is what worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 5):

I got the error when saved with `saveRDS()` rather than `save()`. E.g. `save(iris, file="data/iris.RData")`

This fixed the issue for me. I found this info [here](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/data.html)

Also note that with `save()` / `load()` the object is loaded in with the same name it is initially saved with (i.e you can't rename it until it's already loaded into the R environment under the name it had when you initially saved it).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I saved the Rdata file in an older version of R and then I tried to open in a new one. I solved by updating my R version to the newest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `devtools` try to save the files with:

```
devtools::use_data(x, internal = TRUE)
```

Then, delete all files saved previously.

From doc:

> *internal  If FALSE, saves each object in individual .rda files in the data directory. These are available whenever the package is loaded. If
>   TRUE, stores all objects in a single R/sysdata.rda file. These objects
>   are only available within the package.*

Comment: devtools:: is now usethis::

Answer (score 0):

This error occured when I updated my R and R Studio versions and loaded files I created under my prior version. So I reinstalled my prior R version and everything worked as it should.