# How to remove error : bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded?

Tags: r, workspace, magic-numbers

Using R version 3.3.0 (Windows)

> Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no
>   data loaded
>
> In addition: Warning message: file ‘.RData’ has magic number 'q'   Use
>   of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

During startup - Warning message:

> unable to restore saved data in .RData

I reinstall R but the error is still exist.

Please help to remove this error.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: When we run Rstdio(`RStudio-0.99.902`), it gives the same error and also it stacks at loading workspace from ~/.RData. So i can't able to use Rstdio properly. @DianeBeldame

Comment: You get this error message opening R or Rstudio ? from scratch ?

Comment: No. I works on RStdio but suddenly it crashed and after when i open it, it gives the error.
I reinstall R and RStdio both. But it gives same errors.

Comment: Did you try deleting the .Rdata file?

Comment: Yes, I delete the .Rdata file from workspace. But it still gives error. 

My question is not duplicate. I want to know how to remove this error not to avoid this. I still face this problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you (or RStudio) is trying to `load()` something that isn't a workspace. 
Some explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/what-could-cause-a-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-an-r-workspace-and-how?rq=1)

Comment: I did not try `load()`