# Error when trying to load .RData information

Tags: r

I have been trying to save my R environment to load in later sessions (my environment has about 12 data frames).

```
save.image(file = 'tests.RData')
```

if I look in my directory, my file looks like data has been saved since the .RData file is about 40MB in size.

Now when I try to load the file in the directory...

```
load('test.RData')
```

I get this error:

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data     loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file 'tests.RData' has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I tried looking at previous issues with this, and the only advice was to try load() and source(). However, I believe load() is for .rda/.RData files.

Is there anyway to save my environment and load it properly? What is causing my issue exactly?

Comment: input the full path to the load function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could cause a "bad magic number" error when loading an R workspace and how to avoid it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/what-could-cause-a-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-an-r-workspace-and-how)

Comment: Putting the full path into the load function did not work...if I dir() the directory, I see the .RData file in there as well.

Comment: The other question that was asked unfortunately does not work for me....I am using the load() function for .RData files and am still getting an error message

Comment: have you tried ```source``` instead

Comment: I get this error:        > source('tests.RData')
Error in source("tests.RData") : tests.RData:2:1: unexpected input
1:
2:
   ^

Comment: `source` is for reading and executing R code, not loading data.

Comment: ^^ That's why I'm curious as why I am still getting an error, as everyone seems to assume I'm mixing up load() and source(). My guess would be that there was an issue with the save.image() function...is that the only way to save an environment?

Comment: It's not clear if you're entering the file name correctly. What does `list.files()` say? Is this file present?

Comment: After I enter the command save.image(file = 'tests.RData') and then hit list.files(), I see the 'tests.RData' present

Comment: for some reason sometimes when I save the extension as '.RData', the file is present but is 0kb in size. Everytime when I save the extension as '.rda',  the file is present and is about 40MB in size but gives me the same error when I try to load it. Could it by that there is something weird going on when I try to save a binary file?