# Load .Rda file in R giving error Magic Number

Tags: r, docker, rdata

I am trying to load .Rda file in R woth load() function in a docker container but it's giving me the error "file ‘decrypted_model.Rdata’ **has magic number 'RDX3'**
Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated"

R_BASE_VERSION is 3.6.

caret package version is 6.0-84

I am using image of ubuntu:16.04

I am using load function for this:

```
load('decrypted_model.Rda')
```

Is there any workaround for this or any way to solve this?

Comment: Can check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/the-cause-of-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-a-workspace-and-how-to-avoid

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. I am doing this operation inside docker.