# How to solve "bad restore file magic number" when trying to load data?

Tags: r, workspace, magic-numbers

I tried to load data to my R working directory and receive this error:

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘classize.RData’ has magic number 'RDX3'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I googled it and tried many options, unsuccessfully.

1. My Rstudio version is: 1.2.5033 (The error was happening before updating as well)
2. I create a new project, in the new directory, I put the data file
3. The data file is "classize.RData"
4. I have another alternative which is "classize.RDS" with the sugesstion to use `readRDS(file = "classize.RDS")`. When using this command, I receive that error:

```
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer
```

This is in the context of a statistical course at university and my teacher assistant is unable to help me out, and whitout resolving this issue, I cannot move forward in the resolution of the needed exrecices. So please, couly you help me resolve that problem.

ps: all the students have access to the same data, It's just for me that it's not working, therefore the file should not be corrupted.

Comment: What is the code that you run to load the data?

Comment: Also, it kind of suggests that you need to update your R. If this is the case, you can just google, how to do it.

Comment: Use source() or readRDS() while loading the data, as suggested in the post 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/the-cause-of-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-a-workspace-and-how-to-avoid

Also, upload R to the latest version

Comment: I just updated my R and the issue keeps happening.
I tried : 
- readRDS(file = "classize.RDS")
- object <-readRDS("classize.RDS")
- load("/Users/charles/Documents/Uni/4th sremester/stat2/project")
load("classize.RData")

Doesn't work...

Comment: Thank you for the link to this previous post, nonetheless I already saw it and tried everything suggested without any success...

Comment: What version of R are you using?  You need version 3.5.0 or newer, as the message says.  The version of RStudio is independent of the version of R:  RStudio is just the editor and front end, R does the work of loading the file.

Comment: It was indeed that. My version of R wasn't up to date and updating it resolved the issue. Thank you  @user2554330 for pointing out this difference between R and RStudio.