# Opening RData objects

Tags: r, rdata

I am trying to open an RData object that I downloaded from github, using the load function.
I have tried in a few versions of R (going back to 3.4.0 and 4.2.0) and receive the same error message, pasted below.
Thanks!

```
Error in load(paste0(mydir, "/", loadDir, "/", ssn.folder, "/object.RData")) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘object.RData’ has magic number 'versi'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The cause of "bad magic number" error when loading a workspace and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/the-cause-of-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-a-workspace-and-how-to-avoid)

Comment: No, none of the suggestions on that page work

Comment: OK, can you share the link to the GitHub repository where you got this .RData file from?